# Pandas: Comparing rows within groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that is grouped by 'Key'. I need to compare rows within each group to identify whether I want to keep each row of the group or whether I want just one row of a group.

In the condition to keep all rows of a group: if there is one row that has the color 'red' and area of '12' and shape of 'circle' AND another row (within the same group) that has a color of 'green' and an area of '13' and shape of 'square', then I want to keep all rows in that group. Otherwise if this scenario does not exist, I want to keep the row of that group with the largest 'num' value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['100000009', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009','100000034','100000034', '100000034'], 
              'Date1': [20120506, 20120506, 20120507,20120608,20120620,20120206,20120306,20120405],
              'shape': ['circle', 'square', 'circle','circle','circle','circle','circle','circle'],
              'num': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
              'area': [12, 13, 12,12,12,12,12,12],
              'color': ['red', 'green', 'red','red','red','red','red','red']})


    Date1       KEY        area color   num shape
0   2012-05-06  100000009   12  red     3   circle
1   2012-05-06  100000009   13  green   4   square
2   2012-05-07  100000009   12  red     5   circle
3   2012-06-08  100000009   12  red     6   circle
4   2012-06-20  100000009   12  red     7   circle
5   2012-02-06  100000034   12  red     8   circle
6   2012-03-06  100000034   12  red     9   circle
7   2012-04-05  100000034   12  red     10  circle
```

Expected result:

```
    Date1       KEY        area color   num shape
0   2012-05-06  100000009   12  red     3   circle
1   2012-05-06  100000009   13  green   4   square
2   2012-05-07  100000009   12  red     5   circle
3   2012-06-08  100000009   12  red     6   circle
4   2012-06-20  100000009   12  red     7   circle
7   2012-04-05  100000034   12  red     10  circle
```

I am new to python, and groupby is throwing me a curve ball.

```
maxnum = df.groupby('KEY')['num'].transform(max)
df = df.loc[df.num == maxnum]

cond1 = (df[df['area'] == 12]) & (df[df['color'] == 'red']) & (df[df['shape'] == 'circle'])
cond2 = (df[df['area'] == 13]) & (df[df['color'] == 'green']) & (df[df['shape'] == 'square'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a custom function called `function`:

```
def function(x):
    i = x.query(
        'area == 12 and color == "red" and shape == "circle"'
    )
    j = x.query(
        'area == 13 and color == "green" and shape == "square"'
    )
    return x if not (i.empty or j.empty) else x[x.num == x.num.max()].head(1)
```

This function tests each group on the specified conditions and returns rows as appropriate. In particular, it queries on the conditions and tests for emptiness using `df.empty`.

Pass this to `groupby` + `apply`:

```
df.groupby('KEY', group_keys=False).apply(function)


      Date1        KEY  area  color  num   shape
0  20120506  100000009    12    red    3  circle
1  20120506  100000009    13  green    4  square
2  20120507  100000009    12    red    5  circle
3  20120608  100000009    12    red    6  circle
4  20120620  100000009    12    red    7  circle
7  20120405  100000034    12    red   10  circle
```