# Comparing rows within groups, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

What I need seems kind of basic, but I'm struggling with it, so I would appreciate your help.

This code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a100', 'a100', 'a100', 'a200', 'a200', 'a200','a300','a300', 'a300', 'a400', 'a400', 'a400', 'a500', 'a500', 'a500', 'a600', 'a600', 'a600', 'a700', 'a700', 'a700', 'a800', 'a800', 'a800', 'a900', 'a900', 'a900'],
                    'type': ['euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen','euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen'],
                   'model': ['EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'MC', 'MC', 'MC', 'EQ','EQ', 'EQ', 'MC', 'MC', 'MC', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ'],
                    'status_ant': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                    'status': ['B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']
                    })
```

that results in this df:

```
      id    type model status_ant status
0   a100    euro    EQ          A      B
1   a100  dollar    EQ          A      C
2   a100     yen    EQ          A      A
3   a200    euro    MC          A      B
4   a200  dollar    MC          A      C
5   a200     yen    MC          A      A
6   a300    euro    EQ          B      A
7   a300  dollar    EQ          C      A
8   a300     yen    EQ          A      A
9   a400    euro    MC          B      A
10  a400  dollar    MC          C      A
11  a400     yen    MC          A      A
12  a500    euro    EQ          A      B
13  a500  dollar    EQ          A      C
14  a500     yen    EQ          A      B
15  a600    euro    EQ          B      A
16  a600  dollar    EQ          C      A
17  a600     yen    EQ          B      A
18  a700    euro    EQ          A      A
19  a700  dollar    EQ          A      A
20  a700     yen    EQ          A      B
21  a800    euro    EQ          A      B
22  a800  dollar    EQ          A      A
23  a800     yen    EQ          A      B
24  a900    euro    EQ          A      A
25  a900  dollar    EQ          A      C
26  a900     yen    EQ          A      C
```

I need to filter the rows I want using some conditions. The logic I need is this one:

- First of all, these conditions I will mention should only apply to rows where model == 'EQ'.
- If there's a row where:

```
status_ant == 'A' and status == 'B' and type == 'euro'
```

AND there's another row WITHIN the same group (by id) where

```
status_ant == 'A' and status == 'C' and type == 'dollar'
```

drop those two rows (else, keep them). The same logic applies for rows were:

```
status_ant == 'B' and status == 'A' and type == 'euro'
```

AND there's another row WITHIN the same group (by id) where

```
status_ant == 'C' and status == 'A' and type == 'dollar'
```

The row with type == 'yen' shouldn't be dropped whatever the values in status_ant and status are.

**Note**: I know it might be confusing, but the resulting dataframe I want is this one (it exemplifies very well all the conditions I mentioned):

```
      id    type model status_ant status
2   a100     yen    EQ          A      A
3   a200    euro    MC          A      B
4   a200  dollar    MC          A      C
5   a200     yen    MC          A      A
8   a300     yen    EQ          A      A
9   a400    euro    MC          B      A
10  a400  dollar    MC          C      A
11  a400     yen    MC          A      A
14  a500     yen    EQ          A      B
17  a600     yen    EQ          B      A
18  a700    euro    EQ          A      A
19  a700  dollar    EQ          A      A
20  a700     yen    EQ          A      B
21  a800    euro    EQ          A      B
22  a800  dollar    EQ          A      A
23  a800     yen    EQ          A      B
24  a900    euro    EQ          A      A
25  a900  dollar    EQ          A      C
26  a900     yen    EQ          A      C
```

I was looking for the answer and found something similar here: [Pandas: Comparing rows within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819644/pandas-comparing-rows-within-groups)
but couldn't make it work for my code.

Really appreciate your help and your time.
Thank you

Comment: are you only dropping those four conditions? If so, I can post a solution, but if you have more conditions than those, then it wouldn't work. Are you filtering on D, E, F too?

Comment: I dont think this is possible right? `status_ant == 'A' and status == 'B', AND status_ant == 'A' and status == 'C'`. Are you referring to records that have either of these combinations?

Comment: @JonathanLeon I have more rows to apply those conditions, but I will update my post as soon as possible with a more detailed dataframe. Thank you

Comment: @JoeFerndz I'm referring to group of rows (for each id) where those two conditions exist. I will update the post with a better dataframe sample soon. Thank you

Comment: This code should still work for the dataset - print (df[~(df.model.eq('EQ') & df.status_ant.ne(df.status))])

Comment: The only issue now (with the update) is that your code also filters some rows it shouldn't @JoeFerndz :/  (that have the same status_ant and status but are a different type), but it's almost there!

Comment: Also, if any of the status columns value is 'D' for a row with type == 'yen', keep that row (like you did before). Thank you

Comment: Are these the only conditions or do we have additional dynamic conditions to consider?

Comment: Hello @JoeFerndz . I just updated it the best I could. This is the final update I will make. Sorry for that, and thanks again

Comment: Can the community experts in Pandas look at this please? I am having a challenge with trying to check multiple rows within a group. One way to do this is to create a pd.Series and check it. That's not working for me

Comment: @HaRambe, the expert has reviewed and given the answer. Please review and see if you understood the solution.

Comment: Sure @JoeFerndz , I will look at it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution if for each `id` are unique values of column `type` is possible test if sum of `True`s per groups is `2`:

```
m0 = data['model']=='EQ' 
m1 = (data['status_ant'] == 'A') & (data['status'] == 'B') & (data['type'] == 'euro')
m2 = (data['status_ant'] == 'A') & (data['status'] == 'C') & (data['type'] == 'dollar')

m3 = (data['status_ant'] == 'B') & (data['status'] == 'A') & (data['type'] == 'euro')
m4 = (data['status_ant'] == 'C') & (data['status'] == 'A') & (data['type'] == 'dollar')

mask = m0 & (m1 | m2 | m3 | m4)

mask_groups = mask.groupby(data['id']).transform('sum').eq(2)

data = data[~mask | ~mask_groups]
print (data)
      id    type model status_ant status
2   a100     yen    EQ          A      A
3   a200    euro    MC          A      B
4   a200  dollar    MC          A      C
5   a200     yen    MC          A      A
8   a300     yen    EQ          A      A
9   a400    euro    MC          B      A
10  a400  dollar    MC          C      A
11  a400     yen    MC          A      A
14  a500     yen    EQ          A      B
17  a600     yen    EQ          B      A
18  a700    euro    EQ          A      A
19  a700  dollar    EQ          A      A
20  a700     yen    EQ          A      B
21  a800    euro    EQ          A      B
22  a800  dollar    EQ          A      A
23  a800     yen    EQ          A      B
24  a900    euro    EQ          A      A
25  a900  dollar    EQ          A      C
26  a900     yen    EQ          A      C
```

---

If possible values are not unique is possible test by `any` if match per groups, chnaged data for `a100`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a100', 'a100', 'a100', 'a200', 'a200', 'a200','a300','a300', 'a300', 'a400', 'a400', 'a400', 'a500', 'a500', 'a500', 'a600', 'a600', 'a600', 'a700', 'a700', 'a700', 'a800', 'a800', 'a800', 'a900', 'a900', 'a900'],
                    'type': ['euro', 'dollar', 'dollar', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen','euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'yen'],
                   'model': ['EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'MC', 'MC', 'MC', 'EQ','EQ', 'EQ', 'MC', 'MC', 'MC', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ'],
                    'status_ant': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                    'status': ['B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']
                    })
```

---

```
m0 = data['model']=='EQ' 
m1 = (data['status_ant'] == 'A') & (data['status'] == 'B') & (data['type'] == 'euro')
m2 = (data['status_ant'] == 'A') & (data['status'] == 'C') & (data['type'] == 'dollar')

m3 = (data['status_ant'] == 'B') & (data['status'] == 'A') & (data['type'] == 'euro')
m4 = (data['status_ant'] == 'C') & (data['status'] == 'A') & (data['type'] == 'dollar')

mask1 = m0 & (m1 | m3)
mask2 = m0 & (m2 | m4)

mask_euro = mask1.groupby(data['id']).transform(any)
mask_dolar = mask2.groupby(data['id']).transform(any)

data = data[~(mask1 | mask2) | ~(mask_euro & mask_dolar)]
```

---

```
print (data)
     id    type model status_ant status
3   a200    euro    MC          A      B
4   a200  dollar    MC          A      C
5   a200     yen    MC          A      A
8   a300     yen    EQ          A      A
9   a400    euro    MC          B      A
10  a400  dollar    MC          C      A
11  a400     yen    MC          A      A
14  a500     yen    EQ          A      B
17  a600     yen    EQ          B      A
18  a700    euro    EQ          A      A
19  a700  dollar    EQ          A      A
20  a700     yen    EQ          A      B
21  a800    euro    EQ          A      B
22  a800  dollar    EQ          A      A
23  a800     yen    EQ          A      B
24  a900    euro    EQ          A      A
25  a900  dollar    EQ          A      C
26  a900     yen    EQ          A      C
```

Comment: This is brilliant. You are doing the mask on groupby and checking value eq(2). I was stuck in this part. Now i get it. Thanks for the solution. It makes sense.

Comment: @JoeFerndz - Ya, another problem is cannot use `isin`, because it match also `A,A` and `B,B`

Comment: Yeah. Thats where I was stuck. I was trying with isin and didnt get my head out of it. Should have gone your route to force each one. Was trying to see if I could grab both. Wow. You are awesome at this.

Comment: @JoeFerndz - Hmm, do you think `type` are unique per `id` ? If not, solution not working.

Comment: This isn't my problem statement. I assume it is unique. I was eliminating the duplicates when I was trying to do my solution approach. So i filter on EQ and type isin dollar euro. Then remove duplicates (keep=first). that becomes my base to start with. If we have two euro EQ A B, then things fall apart.

Comment: Hi guys. Yes, the types are unique for each id, and the code works :) It was indeed a challenge, but hey I learned something new today. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

## Run against updated Data:

Code is still the same:

```
print (df[~(df.model.eq('EQ') & df.status_ant.ne(df.status))])
```

Input Data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a100', 'a100', 'a100', 'a200', 'a200', 'a200','a300','a300', 'a300', 'a400', 'a400', 'a400'],
                    'model' : ['EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'MC', 'MC', 'MC', 'EQ','EQ', 'EQ', 'MC', 'MC', 'MC', ],
                     'status_ant' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
                     'status': ['B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
                     })
```

This got loaded into the DataFrame as:

```
      id model status_ant status
0   a100    EQ          A      B  #exclude this row
1   a100    EQ          A      C  #exclude this row
2   a100    EQ          A      A
3   a200    MC          A      B
4   a200    MC          A      C
5   a200    MC          A      A
6   a300    EQ          B      A #exclude this row
7   a300    EQ          C      A #exclude this row
8   a300    EQ          A      A
9   a400    MC          B      A
10  a400    MC          C      A
11  a400    MC          A      A
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
      id model status_ant status
2   a100    EQ          A      A
3   a200    MC          A      B
4   a200    MC          A      C
5   a200    MC          A      A
8   a300    EQ          A      A
9   a400    MC          B      A
10  a400    MC          C      A
11  a400    MC          A      A
```

## Earlier Answer

Are you looking for this:

```
print (df[~(df.model.eq('EQ') & df.status_ant.ne(df.status))])
```

Note that you don't need to do a group by. You cannot do a group by as you are actually trying to get a subset of the data.

First it will check if `df['model'] == 'EQ'`. If true, then it will check if `df['status_ant'] != df['status']`.

By giving `df['status_ant'] != df['status']`, you are checking for all the conditions.

`status_ant == 'A' and status == 'B', AND status_ant == 'A' and status == 'C'`

and

`status_ant == 'B' and status == 'A', AND status_ant == 'C' and status == 'A'`

The output of this will be:

```
      id model status_ant status
2   a100    EQ          A      A
3   a200    MC          A      B
4   a200    MC          A      C
5   a200    MC          A      A
8   a300    EQ          A      A
9   a400    MC          B      A
10  a400    MC          C      A
11  a400    MC          A      A
```

Note: If you have other values in `status_ant` and `status`, this will NOT work. For example, if `status_ant` is `A` and `status` is `D` or `E` and you want that record to be included, then I need to add an additional condition.

If you want to limit the check only for `A`, `B` and `C`, then you can give this:

```
print (df[~(df.model.eq('EQ') & df.status_ant.isin(['A','B','C']) & df.status.isin(['A','B','C']) & df.status_ant.ne(df.status))])
```

The output of this will be:

Source Code I used to create the input DataFrame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a100', 'a100', 'a100', 'a100','a200', 'a200', 'a200','a300','a300', 'a300', 'a400', 'a400', 'a400'],
                    'model' : ['EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ', 'EQ','MC', 'MC', 'MC', 'EQ','EQ', 'EQ', 'MC', 'MC', 'MC', ],
                     'status_ant' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
                     'status': ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
                     })
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Input DataFrame:

```
      id model status_ant status
0   a100    EQ          A      B  #exclude this row
1   a100    EQ          A      C  #exclude this row
2   a100    EQ          A      A    #include this row
3   a100    EQ          A      D    #include this row
4   a200    MC          A      B
5   a200    MC          A      C
6   a200    MC          A      A
7   a300    EQ          B      A  #exclude this row
8   a300    EQ          C      A  #exclude this row
9   a300    EQ          A      A    #include this row
10  a400    MC          B      A
11  a400    MC          C      A
12  a400    MC          A      A
```

Output DataFrame:

```
      id model status_ant status
2   a100    EQ          A      A   #included
3   a100    EQ          A      D   #included
4   a200    MC          A      B
5   a200    MC          A      C
6   a200    MC          A      A
9   a300    EQ          A      A   #included
10  a400    MC          B      A
11  a400    MC          C      A
12  a400    MC          A      A
```

See index 3. It has `status = 'D'` and is included in your result set.

Comment: ya, it seems complicated.

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for looking into this. its definitely complicated. May need to look at slide and then put all of them together. Even thought about concat of the conditions into a column then shift(1). Left it half way. Need to think thru this a bit

Comment: hmmm, first what is n my head is necessary test per groups?

Comment: i took a slice (mask) of just the model = EQ and type in (euro, dollar), then tried to find out if the combination of the two conditions are in it. The problem is, to get the groupby values and the two rows as a set to check. Dont know how to get the two rows that meet the condition. We need to test by each group for the results and filter out

Comment: ya, not easy, maybe now understand it.